# Installing smart switch that needs a neutral wire without a neutral wire

Tags: wiring

I live in the Philippines and we don't have neutral wires. I got a Wink Relay 2 years ago but it is a 110v system, something I couldn't use here. But recently I found a way to convert it to 230v.

When I tried to replace a 2 gang switch with my Wink Relay. I saw that there are only 3 wires. Unfortunately the Wink Relay requires a neutral wire to power itself.

What are my options in this? Can I use the line/live as the neutral?

———

I don’t think there are more wires at the back because the wires are coming from above, see photo:

[image]

The wire with a masking tape is the live. The other 2 are the loads.

And this was how the wiring of the original switch was done. 4 wires in total, but the 4th one is really short and just connecting the switches.

[image]

Comment: You're sure you don't have a neutral? Your power outlet has two contacts. One is "hot" the other is "neutral". If there were a third, it would be "safety ground" or just "ground".

Comment: I'm connecting this to a switch though. Can I do something about that?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking? Say "ground" when you mean ground and "neutral" when you mean neutral.

Comment: Sure but I'm not talking about ground at all. Just the neutral. If I understand correctly the Wink Relay is powered through the neutral wire. I don't have proper electrical education though and just trying to hack this in. Sorry.

Comment: @ThePhoton - There are some less common, "single-wire" transmission systems that forgo the neutral and just ground at the source. I think they have that in Brazil and some areas of Australia, perhaps the Philippines too?

Comment: You say you don't have a neutral wire, but that's almost certainly not true. If your plugs aren't polarized you might not know which wire in the appliance is going to be hot and which is going to be neutral, but you almost surely do have a neutral wire. (Unless you have two hot phases, but that would cost more for the utility company so it seems unlikely)

Comment: @Bort, then they could still treat the ground wire as neutral (because it would be being used that way).

Comment: OP, when you say "2 gang switch" you mean something that looks like [this](https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/smartthings/uploads/default/original/3X/7/0/708af3fcd5145aba1d1dd42d639c6a64b48fa0c6.JPG)?

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, something with 2 switches. And our appliances here can be plugged in either direction. I understand we use 2 phase, both wires are live.

Comment: OK, if that's true then you basically have the same thing as a US 240-V circuit, and [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106754/do-both-legs-in-220v-have-to-be-switched) is relevant. How you will get the Wink to switch both legs I don't know.

Comment: @ThePhoton unfortunately I don't understand what these legs are? :)

Comment: legs = wires. You want to switch both lines to the load so that when it's switched off it will be fully de-energized (in case somebody sticks their finger inside, for example)

Comment: I think the OP is trying to install a device which requires a neutral **into a lighting switch wall-box that doesn't have a neutral**. If so s/he should edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @Transistor this is correct. Sorry, for the misleading question. I'll try to edit it.

Comment: Ook behind the switches in the back ofthe junction  box. What other wires are back there?  How are they grouped into cables?  Preferably post a photo of the back of the box.

Comment: @Harper updated my question with a photo.

Comment: Holy smoke! **That's conduit!**  This will be easier than expected.  What's going on at the other end of that conduit? You may need to open up other boxes to see.

Answer (score 4):

While the Philippines have some unusual power configurations, none of that has any bearing here. OP has the modified Euro style hookup, where ground is centered halfway between the live conductors, 120V from either conductor.  Pick either supply wire to act as "neutral" here, just be consistent.

This is a **switch loop**.  What makes it special is it's a 3-wire switch loop because it controls two appliances, just as OP says. But it still has all the normal properties of a switch loop.

Including the absence of a neutral and thus, inability to power *powered* switches such as smart switches.

OP's options are:

- if it's conduit,  just fish another wire to be the opposite leg.
- Replace the cable to the switch with /4 cable, which has 4 wires and ground. /3 will not do, do not use a ground wire for a neutral *especially not in the Philippines*.
- Make both appliances switch together, freeing up the needed wire.
- Find smart devices able to power themselves old-school by leaking small amounts of power through the load.
- Find a smart device able to live up in the ceiling rose, and be remotely controlled in some way.
- Give up the project.

Comment: I do have smart light bulbs that can be turned on via wifi. How does that help? And what does make both appliance switch together? The 2 connections are both light bulbs on the ceiling. One inside the house, the other outside. The switch is right next to the door.

Comment: That means you get rid of one switch and the remaining switch operates both bulbs.  Doesn't sound like the right solution here.

Comment: When you say pick either supply wire to act as neutral, you mean the wire from the electric pole outside? My switch is wired from the breaker. Only one wire is coming into the switch, both switches (2 gang) is powered thru that one wire. The other 2 wires are the wires going to the light. 3 total wires inside the box and 1 wire connecting switch 1 to switch 2.

Comment: I meant the wire from one of the loads.  **Wait. Have you looked in the *back* of the box behind the switches? Are any other wires there?**  
If not,  The smart bulbs are similar to my "module in the ceiling rose" option. They may be the key to success.

Comment: If I understand correctly. I’m going to use the other load as the neutral? And use a smart light bulb on the light for the switch instead? My smart light bulb is a E27 Lifx.